# Table rows made visible with JQuery changing overall column layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem involves a table containing some permanently visible rows and some that are generated at load time and defaulted to `display: none`. The actual project generates 255 rows using a PHP loop, each with a unique **id**, and unique fields within them.

```js
$('#numFields').change(function(){
    var numFields = $('#numFields').val()
    for (x = 1; x <= numFields; x++) {
        $('#fieldInfoRow'+x).css('display', 'block');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of Fields:</td>
        <td><input id='numFields' type='number' min='1' max='255' /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="fieldInfoRow1" style="display: none;">
        <td>Column 1 heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field1Name"></td>
        <td>Data type:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field1DataType"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="fieldInfoRow2" style="display: none;">
        <td>Column 2 heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field2Name"></td>
        <td>Data type:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field2DataType"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="fieldInfoRow3" style="display: none;">
        <td>Column 3 heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field3Name"></td>
        <td>Data type:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field3DataType"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="fieldInfoRow4" style="display: none;">
        <td>Column 4 heading:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field4Name"></td>
        <td>Data type:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="field4DataType"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As shown in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8Lsn3uu/), entering an integer into the 'Number of Fields' box defines the number of rows to make visible. *N.B. I have only included 4 rows as I could not use PHP to create them.*

The problem I am having is the right-hand `<td>` elements that are already present being pushed over and the left-hand ones (plain text) spanning the four new columns that are made visible using `display: block`. I have tried using things like `colspan` on the existing `<td>` elements to no avail.

I'm sure it's something plain and simple to do with the styling but I'm just totally out of ideas; any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I edited it, added code inline, it's highly recommended when you ask any question next time.

Comment: Cheers - I simply thought JSFiddle may provide quicker understanding of the context. Many thanks for your help - I am fairly new to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it's because the default display type of a table item isn't `block`. Switch `display: block;` to display: `table-row;` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks daymannovaes ! Along with `table-layout: fixed` and 2 `visibility: hidden` `<td>` elements this created an even layout. Thanks!